# data change in Provider variable but widget can't show data and return nothing

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

[image] i have an array in my Provider class like this

```
  List<String> _modelImages = [];
  List<String> get modelImages {
    return [..._modelImages];
  }
```

and i have a function that add data to array

```
 void addModel(dynamic modelSelected) async {
    try {
      var isExist = _modelImages.contains(modelSelected["id"]);
      if (!isExist) {
        _modelImages.add(modelSelected["id"]);
        print(_modelImages);
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

when i print array in up function show me that String added to array
but i have other funciton like below

```
  void showMe() {
    print(_modelImages);
  }
```

my problem is when i want to print _modelImages array in ShowMe function show me empty array

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you calling this show me function

Comment: when you print _modelImages in addModel function, does it print something or empty?

Comment: @Wilson Toribio the problem was for set changeNotifierProvider in on up level but is use in higher level multi provider in main.dart file i removed changeNotifierProvider in one up level problem solved thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

the problem was for set changeNotifierProvider in on up level but is use in higher level multi provider in main.dart file i removed changeNotifierProvider in one up level problem solved thanks guys

when face with these problems like this just go one up level and remove ChangeNotifierProvider
for example

```
body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => YOUR_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME(),
          child: Container(
            child: YOUR_WIDGER(
          ),
        ));
```

and leave Container alone for this example
but you should use multi provider in highest level before